# Set up RPi2 as a local website for I/O control

Tags: gpio, wifi, web-server, server

I am making a drink making robot. I was going to set the RPi as a webpage that can only be accessed when on my local Wifi network.

Then on the page you would select what drink you want and when the user hits submit the pour commands are sent to python I/O control.

My problem is the first half, how do I set up a local webpage and have it submit say an array of int to a python program on the pi. Any ideas on what I should do? or how I should tackle this?

Comment: I did such things with websockets. Setup simple web server on RPi (e.g. nginx) & write websocket server. If your application would be standalone, you can send html page by itself, without nginx. E.g.: https://github.com/eddyem/rasp-spect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [web.py](http://webpy.org/).

It's a simple web framework for Python.

For example here's a Hello World:

```python
import web

urls = ("/.*", "hello")
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class hello:
    def GET(self):
        return 'Hello, world!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

It even comes with a built-in web server for faster testing.

Answer (score 1):

You may write the whole application in python. Use [BaseHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html).

This is a very basic and simple approach, but you could of course go for websockets and such stuff if you want to learn that. I don't see the immediate need for web sockets in this app, although you can always think of add-ons that would use it.

At work, we use RPi and Python (with BaseHttpServer) to serve web clients that access VNC and SSH connections on Android phones Connected to the RPi over USB. It has it's issues, but it is simple and works.

If you want another simple but more flexible approach; look at [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org)

[Miguel Grinbergs Mega-Tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) is excellent learning material.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up set up a web server such as nginx and use php to run your python scripts. The code can be similar to something like this

```php
<body>
    <?php
        if ($_GET['drink']) {
            $cmd = "export DISPLAY=:0; myscript;";
            exec($cmd);
        }
    ?>
    <a href="?drink=true" class="btn btn-primary" role="button" >Launch script</a>
</body>
```

you may have to change some permissions on your system in order to run the python scripts. I remember I had to do something similar in av virtual machine while trying to do something similar. I will be testing this method on a raspberry pi myself later for my own project

Comment: it probably should be `?drink=true`

Comment: yeah my bad, it was a typo. I have corrected it

Answer (score 0):

I am trying something similar on an abstract level. We are using a database. The webpage will be writing to the database and the program will poll the database for changes.

You could also have a look at http://webiopi.trouch.com/